# Updating Progress Bar on GUI from a different object/class

Tags: c#

I have a class that manages downloading files from a particular resource. The class is instantiated within the GUI thread. For examples sake the class is called `MP3Download`.

Within `MP3Downloader` I have a method called `DownloadFile`:

```
public async Task DownloadFIle(string url, string path)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Changed");
            };

            try
            {
                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, path);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

}

I have a progress bar on the GUI. I want to some how be able to report the progress of the download back to the progress bar.

Would I have to create an event in the `MP3Downloader` class and subscribe to that event from the GUI? When `DownloadProgressChanged` is fired then I pass the sender and event arguments to my custom event?

I don't want to couple the progress bar with the `MP3Downloader` class.

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is yes, use an event. If you want loose coupling, go through an interface. Does that answer your question or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) prescribes proper progress procedure. If you're just interested in the percentage, this would be:

```
public async Task DownloadFIle(string url, string path, IProgress<int> progress = null)
{
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
  {
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
      if (progress != null)
        progress.Report(e.ProgressPercentage);
    };

    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, path);
  }
}
```

Consuming code can use the built-in `Progress<T>` class to respond to the progress updates. Proper thread marshaling is handled by the `Progress<T>` class for you.

Comment: awesome. Implemented in xam

Answer (score 0):

"I don't want to couple the progress bar with the MP3Downloader class"

Yeah, that wouldn't be cool. How about declaring an interface on the View layer and then making the call to the controller through an implementation (injected dependency, use an IoC container), then the `MP3Downloader` class could have a thread that would keep publishing data about the progression of the download to the GUI. It's just an implementation, if you want to reuse the GUI, you will only be carrying the interface with you, i.e., high cohesive & loosely coupled.

Comment: Ah, slight problem as I'm not using an MVC pattern on this project. It's a Winforms app, and I'm just one of the developers.